# When does oscillation of interplanetary plasma occurs?

Tags: planet, photons, radio

When does oscillation of interplanetary plasma occur?

When and what are the reasons of the excitation of this plasma that makes it oscillate? Does it oscillate when is not excited?

Can extremely low radio frequencies pass through it when it is not oscillating?

Comment: Cross posted: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/273449/when-does-oscillation-of-interplanetary-plasma-occurs

Comment: As I stated on the PhysicsSE site, this has the potential of being a good question if you clarify by what you mean when you say _oscillation_ and if you reduce the number of questions (each one could lead to rather lengthy responses).

Comment: Book ref https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=WAg4AAAAIAAJ&source=bl&ots=3QjYneU6KR&sig=RTAmYBjb_ZWIP46mrYGcSrgXR88&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwixv4OSm_XOAhXFCsAKHVWuAyUQ6AEIJDAB#v=onepage&q&f=false